# Is it possible to trigger an action while the user's finger slides into a particular area?

Tags: ios, swift, slide

I am working on an iOS app and I want to have the effect of an action while the user's finger slides into a particular area. I first thought UIButton with touch dragged in will work, but it still requires a touch before the "drag". So is there a way to do it? Thanks so much!

Comment: maybe the UIButtons touch down will trigger while dragging over? (as apposed to the normal touch up inside)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [UITouch](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitouch) with touch began. Have your particular area view as a `UIView` IBOutlet. Lets call it `particularAreaView`

Maybe something like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let touch = touches.allObjects[0] as UITouch //get the latest touch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    let particularAreaViewFrame = self.view.convertRect(particularAreaView.frame, fromView: self.view)

    //Check if touch began is in your particularAreaViewFrame
    if CGRectContainsPoint(particularAreaViewFrame, touchLocation) {
        tiggerYourActionHere()
    }

}
```

If you need it to consider touches that is moving into the area, you will have to override `touchesMoved: withEvent:` as well. Then maybe refactor the above into a function that use in both places.